# How to perform a subtree merge using plumbing commands?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-subtree, git-amend

I want to combine a subtree merge into a regular (non-merge) commit. I currently do this by first performing the subtree merge, then amending this with the regular changes.

```
git merge --strategy subtree --strategy-option subtree=subdir $subdir_parent
# stage changes
git commit --amend -m "message"
```

Is it possible to perform this operation using only plumbing commands? In the commit generated by `git merge`, I see no indication of this being a subtree merge commit. When I pass `$subtree_parent` as the second parent to `git commit-tree`, the resulting commit fails to include the changes of `$subtree_parent`.

**PS. Are there any objections to adding changes to a merge commit that have nothing to do with the merge?**

**EDIT** I think I understand now. Is it simply the tree of the merge commit that determines how the subtree was merged in? Meaning a subtree of the tree equals the top tree of the second parent.

Answer (score 0):

Oops. This was just the result of me being confused about how git works. The tree passed to `git commit-tree` should of course reflect the situation after the merge. I was feeding it the tree without changes to the subdir folder. Simply creating a merge commit using `git commit-tree` does not magically perform the merge!